# NodeJs call a Python script

Tags: python, node.js, heroku

I have this piece of code. It should call my python script if it is true.

The problem is: the script doesn't get executed. I'm using Heroku and I already have nodejs and python in my buildpacks.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

let {PythonShell} = require('python-shell');
app.post('/api/apipath', (req, res) => {
  if (currentPhase == phaseId){
    PythonShell.run('./src/main.py', null, function (err){
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('Finish');
    });
    res.end();
  }else{
    res.end();
  }
}
```

Note: I already forced the condition to be true and it didn't work. The script was not called

Comment: When you say "doesn't get executed" what happens exactly? Is the code really trying to execute the script, or is `currentPhase` always different from `phaseId`?

Comment: I already forced the condition to be true and it didn't work. The script was not called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `python-shell` but you can use `exec` from Node's [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) to run your script

```js
const { exec } = require('child_process')

function runPythonScript(script, runFile = false) {
  console.log(`Run? ${runFile}`)

  if (runFile) {
    exec(`python ${script}`, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (error) {
        console.error(`exec error: ${error}`)
        return
      }
      console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`)
      console.error(`stderr: ${stderr}`)
    })
  }
}
```

Running the code:

```js
// this will run
runPythonScript('./src/main.py', 1 === 1)

// this will not run
runPythonScript('./src/main.py', 0)

// this will run since both currentPhase and phaseId are empty variables 
var currentPhase, phaseId
runPythonScript('./src/main.py', currentPhase === phaseId)
```

---

## CLI

add this code for if you want to define `currentPhase` and `phaseId` from the command line

```
function init() {
  const [, , ...args] = process.argv

  var currentPhase, phaseId
  currentPhase = args[args.indexOf('--currentPhase') - 1]
  phaseId = args[args.indexOf('--phaseId') - 1]

  runPythonScript('./program.py', currentPhase === phaseId)

}
init()
```

from the CLI, you can run

```sh
# sets currentPhase to 99 and phaseId as 98 (does not run)
node lib/filename-to-runPythonScript.js 99 --currentPhase 98 --phaseId

# sets both currentPhase and phaseId to 123 (does run)
node lib/filename-to-runPythonScript.js 123 --currentPhase 123 --phaseId
```